# XSL transform for nested html tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a series of documents output by a Java application that exports XML with html tags unescaped for example as

```
<b>some text</b>
```

( I cannot change this behaviour).

The app that then uses this output must have all html tags escaped to

```
&lt;b&gt;some text &lt;/b&gt;
```

I use the xslt below to escape the tags but not surprisingly it does not work for **nested** html tags, for example where there's

```
<u><b>A string of html</b></u>
```

Upon XSLT transform I get

```
&lt;u&gt;a string of html&lt;/u&gt; 

where nested <b> and </b> tags get removed altogether.
```

I am looking to achieve

```
&lt;u&gt;&lt;b&gt;A string of html&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/u&gt;
```

I am sure there's an easy answer to this by adjusting the value-of select or the template but I have tried and failed dismally

Any help would be much appreciated!

Sample doc with embedded html tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
<Text><u><b>A string of html</b></u></Text>
</Main>
```

This is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;',.,'&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
  <Text>&lt;u&gt;A string of html&lt;/u&gt;</Text>
</Main>
```

The inner bold tags have been dropped as you can see.

Can anyone help with adjusting the xslt?

Thank you :-)

Comment: +1 for a clear and reasonably structured question.

Comment: Can any of the tags you want to "escape" have attributes (e.g. `<a href="http://example.com">link</a>`)?

Comment: Yes they can but this is covered by Tim C's solution below. Thank you for answering anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your current `Text/*` template to this

```
<xsl:template match="Text//*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>
```

So, the `Text//*` will match any descendant element of the **Text** element, not just the immediate child. You then output the opening and closing templates separately, and in between these you recursively call the template to process the 'nested' elements.

When applied to your sample XML, the following should be output

```
<Main>
  <Text>&lt;u&gt;&lt;b&gt;A string of html&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/u&gt;</Text>
</Main>
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, you are a star. That's so brilliantly simple and well, obvious when you know!  I forgot all about XPath syntax.  Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you state in a comment that the tags you're trying to "escape" might have attributes, [Tim C's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095707/592139) is insufficient.  What you actually need is something more like this (since you say the tags in question are HTML I'll assume you don't need to care about namespaces):

```
<xsl:template match="Text//*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="escape" />
  <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" mode="escape">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '=&quot;')" />
  <xsl:call-template name="doubleEscapeQuotes" />
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="doubleEscapeQuotes">
  <xsl:param name="value" select="string(.)" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($value, '&quot;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($value, '&quot;')" />
      <xsl:text>&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="doubleEscapeQuotes">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring-after($value, '&quot;')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

this would convert

```
<a title="An &quot;example&quot; website" href="http://example.com">link</a>
```

into

```
&lt;a title="An &amp;quot;example&amp;quot; website" href="http://example.com"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;
```

but it's still missing some necessary logic - you need to double-escape at least ampersands (`&amp;amp;`) and less-than (`&amp;lt;`) signs as well, in both attribute values *and* in the text content of the HTML elements, in order to keep the resulting markup well-formed after it gets unescaped (you might also like to escape greater-than signs for readability but that's not as crucial as `&` and `<`).

It's a much much harder problem than it would at first appear.  The various answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1162352) may be helpful.

Comment: Ian you are absolutely right of course and thank you for the update, fortunately I discovered that none of the html tags will have attributes after all, and yes you're right again it's very much more complicated than at first sight. Wish I could accept both answers!