# XSLT for inserting the original XML into HTML code tag

Tags: xml, xslt, browser

I have an XML file with an external xsl-stylesheet linked to it. The file looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/xsl/transform.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<test>
    <foo />
</test>
```

I want to copy the entire source code of the untransformed XML into a `<code>` tag. I can use `<xsl:copy-of>` to copy the entire xml tree, but the XML in the code wouldn't be visible in the browser since `<xsl:copy-of>` turns the original XML to actual tags instead of escaped text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <code>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
        </code>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <code>
            &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;
            &lt;?xml-stylesheet href=&quot;/xsl/transform.xsl&quot; type=&quot;text/xsl&quot;?&gt;
            &lt;test&gt;
                &lt;foo /&gt;
            &lt;/test&gt;
        </code>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this transformation possible?

Notes:

1. I don't care whether or not the XML processing instructions (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
    or `<?xml-stylesheet href="/xsl/transform.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>`) are displayed.
2. I'm looking for an XSLT solution, don't suggest using a javascript that reinserts the XML inside the code tag as text.
3. This XSLT will be applied by a browser. I don't care about browser compatibility, if it works in at least one of Firefox or Chrome then it's fine for me.
4. It would be better if the code gets pretty printed or if it preserves whitespaces, but this is optional.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting XML to escaped text in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162352/converting-xml-to-escaped-text-in-xslt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Evan Lenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98316/evan-lenz) stylesheet [**xml-to-string.xsl**](http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl) will achieve what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="xml-to-string.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <code>
                    <xsl:call-template name="xml-to-string">
                        <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="/"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </code>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```